# how to take spesific value in list dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, indexing, functional-programming

here's my whole code

```
a = str(input("parent1 :"))
b = str(input("parent2 :"))


p = {'rose':'R_P_', 'pea':'rrP_'}
print(p[a] +" : "+p[b])

f = []

print('gamet 1 : ' + p[a][0]+p[a][2])
print('gamet 2 : ' + p[b][0]+p[b][2])

g = f

aa=(sorted(p[a][0]+p[b][0]))
bb=(sorted(p[a][2]+p[b][2]))

def convert(s): 

    # initialization of string to "" 
    new = "" 

    # traverse in the string  
    for x in s: 
        new += x  

    # return string  
    return new

gamet = convert(aa)+convert(bb)
gamet1 = list(gamet)
print(gamet +" x " + gamet)

dictgen = {0:gamet[0]+gamet[2], 1:gamet[0]+gamet[3], 2:gamet[1]+gamet[2], 3:gamet[1]+gamet[3]}
l=0
ll=0
gen={}
for k in range(len(dictgen)):
    for j in range(4):
        gen[l] = dictgen[k].join(dictgen[j])
        l += 1
print(gen)
genn={}
for x in range(4):
    for p in range(4):
        genn[ll]=(sorted(convert(gen[p])))
        ll += 1

print(genn)

gen1=[]
for x in range(0,15):
    gen1[x]=genn[x][0].join(genn[x][1])

print(gen1)
```

here's the example about value in genn
{0: ['P', 'P', 'R', 'R'], 1: ['P', 'P', 'R', 'R'], 2: ['P', 'P', 'R', 'r'], 3: ['P', 'P', 'R', 'r'], 4: ['P', 'P', 'R', 'R'], 5: ['P', 'P', 'R', 'R'], 6: ['P', 'P', 'R', 'r'], 7: ['P', 'P', 'R', 'r'], 8: ['P', 'P', 'R', 'R'], 9: ['P', 'P', 'R', 'R'], 10: ['P', 'P', 'R', 'r'], 11: ['P', 'P', 'R', 'r'], 12: ['P', 'P', 'R', 'R'], 13: ['P', 'P', 'R', 'R'], 14: ['P', 'P', 'R', 'r'], 15: ['P', 'P', 'R', 'r']}

i want to take value by index [0] and [1] in genn dictionary value using this code
gen1=[]

```
for x in range(0,15):
    gen1[x]=genn[x][0].join(genn[x][1])

print(gen1)
```

and i got error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-3f9d7067d375> in <module>
     51 gen1=[]
     52 for x in range(0,15):
---> 53     gen1[x]=genn[x][x][0].join(genn[x][x][1])
     54 
     55 print(gen1)

IndexError: string index out of range
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've said you want to run, and the code you've actually run are different.

```
for x in range(0,15):
    gen1[x]=genn[x][0].join(genn[x][1])
```

is not the same as

```
for x in range(0,15):
    gen1[x]=genn[x][x][0].join(genn[x][x][1])
```

Say `x` is 0.

```
genn[0] # -> ['P', 'P', 'R', 'R']
genn[0][0] # -> 'P'
genn[0][0][1] # -> IndexError: string index out of range
```